# mfc OnVScroll not getting called in MDI main frame class

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, mdi

I have a c++ MFC MDI based project using visual studio 2013 community. 
Mainframe class is derived as 
class CMainFrame : public CMDIFrameWndEx

In mainframe class in pre-create, the scroll bar is set as below. 
    cs.style |= WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL;

An `OnVScroll` call back function has been added to receive a call back whenever the main frame scroll bar is moved. `ON_WM_VSCROLL()` has been added to the message map in the mainframe. We find that `OnVScroll` never gets called.
How do we enable callbacks on `OnVScroll` whenever the user moves the `scrollbar`. Any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks & Regards,
Rakesh

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that a scrollbar for `CMDIFrameWndEx` makes no sense.

The `CMDIFrameWndEx` has a child window of type `CMDIClientAreaWnd`,this window covers the complete client area that is left after toolbars and ribbon are created.

So when you create the main frame with the styles `WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL` this styles are removed from the main frame window and transferred to the inner class (the MDI client window).

So the outer frame window will never receive the scroll messages.

You have the MFC source code, just look into the source code of the function `CMDIFrameWnd::CreateClient`! You find the behavior there.

After this is done the `CMDIClientAreaWnd` gets control via a subclass of       the handle `m_hWndMDIClient` to the class `CMDIClientAreaWnd`.

This class is responsible for the MDI-Tab View style.

So if you want the scrollbar messages you may use classic subclassing to the inner MDI Client window.

Spy++ may help you to understand the window structure.

Comment: Thanks xMRI. That's interesting and useful information Will do tests and revert back to you with results.